# unable to get bootloader on Ubuntu12.04

Tags: dual-boot, 64-bit, bootloader

I have dual boot Lenovo laptop g580. I have already Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit installed .

I want Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit that's why I tried to reinstall Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit in place of 32 bit.

After installation I got restart now. Then I got:

```
grub rescue > with invalid ETL
```

Even I am not getting Windows boot also.

Please help me to get bootloader.

Answer (score 0):

Boot your Ubuntu using SuperGrubDisk2 (http://www.supergrubdisk.org/ download the iso and burn it to a CD, then boot from it) and reinstall the bootloader:

- `sudo update-grub`
- `sudo grub-install /dev/sdX` where "X" is the drive letter of your boot-disk (normally "a")